# tkinter ttk progress bar doesnt stop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttkwidgets

can you please help identify the problem and/or suggest alternative solutions?

```
pb = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='determinate',
    length=300
)
pb['maximum'] = 300
pb['value'] = 0
pb.grid(row=3, column=2)
pb.start(1)

while True:
    root.update()
    print("+1")
    if pb['maximum'] <= pb['value']-30:
        pb.stop()
        break
```

i tried to use a loop that stops when the progress bar is full but it just keeps going

Comment: Have you ever tried to print out the result of `pb['maximum'] <= pb['value']-30`? I think it is never `True`.

Comment: No I have not
I'll try
Edit: you were right its never  true, how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand when you want to stop the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two things going on:

First, `value` is capped at 300 as that is the value set as the `maximum`. Once it hits 300 it loops back to zero. This guarantess that `value - 30` is never greater than `maximum`.

Second, printing `value` shows that it increments in both even and odd amounts. This can easily result in `value` exceeding the 300 cap and resetting before it can be evaluated by the `if` statement. It ends up being luck of the draw whether `value` reaches 300 exactly.

Run the code below for a few cycles and it should stop for you. Hope this helps.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    orient='horizontal',
    mode='determinate',
    length=300
)
pb['maximum'] = 300
pb['value'] = 0
pb.grid(row=3, column=2)
pb.start(1)

while True:

    # do stuff for a while
    time.sleep(.02)

    pb['value'] += 1
    print(pb['value'])

    if pb['value'] >= pb['maximum']:
        pb.stop()
        break

    root.update()
```

Edit: Adding the following `if` statement after the sleep seems to result in completing the loop on the first time every time.

```
if pb['value'] > 295:
    pb['value'] = 300
```